# SikuliX1.1.4に同梱のRobot FrameworkでLog.htmlにTake Screenshotのイメージが埋め込まれない

Tags: python, rpa, sikulix

#### **概要**

SikulixにバンドルされているRobot Frameworkをつかっています。

テストケース(.robot)内にスクリーンショットを取得するキーワード(Take Screenshot)を記述すれば

Log.html内にテスト結果とともに
画面イメージが埋め込まれるはずなのですが、
埋め込まれずに困っています。

同様の事象は関連サイトにもあり、対処方法も実施しているのですが
デバッグコードを入れたところ、原因が異なっているようで
どうすれば埋め込まれるようになるのか困っているところです。

原因、対処についてご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示ください。

#### **環境**

- Windows7 Enterprise 64bit
- SikuliX 1.1.4
- Robot Framework(SikuliX 1.1.4にバンドルされているもの)
- Python 2.7.1(SikuriX 1.1.4にバンドルされているもの）
- SikulixIDE 1.1.4

#### **やったこと**

- ソースコード

**Robot_Run_01.sikuli/sample.robot**（robotのスクリプト）
    ```RobotFramework

```
*** Variables ***

*** Settings ***
Library  OperatingSystem
Library  TestLib.sikuli/TestLib.py
Library  Screenshot  ${OUTPUT DIR}   width=640px

*** Test Cases ***
テストケース1
スクリーンショットを撮る ${TEST NAME}_Before
電卓を表示する
スクリーンショットを撮る ${TEST NAME}_After



*** Keywords ***
電卓を表示する
open_calc

スクリーンショットを撮る ${NAME}
Take Screenshot   ${NAME}
```

**TestLib.sikuli/Testlib.py**（計算機の起動を待つ、簡単なSikuliスクリプト）

````
# coding: utf-8
from sikuli import *
# from __future__ import with_statement

class TestLib(object):
    def open_calc(self):
        self.calc = App.open("calc")
        wait("1536568964767.png",1)

```
````

**Robot_Run_01.sikuli/Robot_Run_01.py**（Robotを起動するスクリプト。SikulixIDEから実行）

```
from threading import currentThread

prepareRobot()
workdir = getBundleFolder()

testdata = "sample.robot"

datasource = os.path.join(workdir,testdata)

# Log.htmlに画像が埋め込まれない現象の対処のため
# 下記サイトを参考にThead名を明示的に指定➡解消せず
# https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rfw-users-jp/Z3YaEGgz3Wk
# https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/294598
currentThread().name = 'MainThread'

robot.run(datasource,outputdir=workdir)
```

- 実行結果
  (** SikulixIDE **)

  [image: ![イメージ説明](d6211972ecf64a3c94f4a05c10607d6a.png)]

  (**Log.html**) 画像が埋め込まれるはずが、埋め込まれない
  [image: ![![**Log.html**](e78e00646666f7bad250fb62b6d2f6c4.png)]

#### **ためしたこと**

- **Thread名を明示的に指定した**
  [ここ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rfw-users-jp/Z3YaEGgz3Wk)と[ここ](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/294598)を見て、Thread名が"Mainthead"または"RobotFrameworkTimeoutThread"以外だと
  logが呼ばれないということだったので、robot.run()をコールする前にThread名を明示的に指定したが改善されなかった。
- **Debug用にコードを入れて状態を確認**
  改善されなかったため、念のためデバッグコードを入れ、Thread名を確認したが、期待通りMainthreadになっていた。

(** librarylogger.py  **) 

[image: ![イメージ説明](6aa5db9b211a8212c340662a3e31379e.png)]

Output.xmlでは期待通り"MainThread"となっている(画像へのリンクは埋め込まれている・・)

(** output.xml**)
[image: ![イメージ説明](176d86adcc2e2ab07a0aee16351f9e50.png)]

Answer (score 0):

原因がわかったわけではありませんが、Sikurix1.1.4に同梱のRobot Framework3.0を最新の3.0.4に置き換えることでやりたいことができるようになりました。

具体的には
C:\Users\ユーザ名\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\Lib\robot
の中身をすべて入れかえたら問題が解消しました。